# A magento extension, with buy x more and free shipping

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am looking for a extension that can do so when a customer buys for 100$ then they will get free shipping.

Like this site: www.elekcig.dk

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Enable Free Shipping Magento Open Source, 1.9.x**

It can be based on a minimum purchase, or set up as a shopping cart price rule that applies when a set of conditions is met. If both apply to the same order, the configuration setting will take precedence over the shopping cart rule.

To set up free shipping:

**1.    On the Admin menu, select System > Configuration.**

In the panel on the left, under Sales, select Shipping Methods.

Complete the free shipping settings for any carrier service that you want to use for free shipping.

[image]

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/shipping/free-shipping.html
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rule-shopping-cart-free-shipping.html